# retrieve MySQL auto increment in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql2o

I'm trying to retrieve idPatient from the database but i keep getting errors, idPatient is auto increment. But i don't know if that's what causing the problem.

This is the code i'm trying

```
public List<Patient> getPatientsFromDatabase() {
    String sql = "SELECT naam, voornaam, gebit, idPatient from patienten";
    try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
        return con.createQuery(sql)
                .throwOnMappingFailure(false)
                .executeAndFetch(Patient.class);
    }
}
```

the DB:

[image]

The error:

[image]

Edit - Patient:

```
public Patient(String voornaam, String naam, String gebit, int id) {
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
    this.naam = naam;
    this.id = id;
    if (null != gebit)switch (gebit) {
        case "melkgebit":
            g = new Melkgebit();
            this.gebit = "melkgebit";
            break;
        case "volwassengebit":
            g = new Volwassengebit();
            this.gebit = "volwassengebit";
            break;
        case "wisselgebit":
            this.gebit = "wisselgebit";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the property idPatient  in Patient class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping between columns and properties are done automatically by name. Of course this is not always possible

In your case you have defined id (java properties) as idPatient  (corresponding column in the database table). **The easiest solution for this, is to use aliases in sql queries.**

Try to change your sql:

```
SELECT naam, voornaam, gebit, idPatient id from patienten;
```

For more information visit http://www.sql2o.org/docs/column-mappings/

Answer (score 2):

It seems `Patient` doesn't have the property `idPatient`. Check it

Comment: I added Patient on top, I thinks that's ok